# .net core - Passing an unknown number of IProgress<T> to class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a console app which uses a class library to execute some long running tasks. This is a .net core console app and uses the .net core Generic Host. I also use the [ShellProgressBar](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/shellprogressbar) library to display some progress bars.

My Hosted service looks like this

```
internal class MyHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly IProgress<MyCustomProgress> _progress;
    private readonly IApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;
    private readonly ProgressBar _progressBar;
    private readonly IProgressBarFactory _progressBarFactory;

    public MyHostedService(
        ILogger<MyHostedService> logger, 
        IMyService myService,
        IProgressBarFactory progressBarFactory,
        IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _myService = myService;
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
        _progressBarFactory = progressBarFactory;

        _progressBar = _progressBarFactory.GetProgressBar();        // this just returns an instance of ShellProgressBar

        _progress = new Progress<MyCustomProgress>(progress =>
        {
            _progressBar.Tick(progress.Current);
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _progressBar.Dispose();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _myService.RunJobs(_progress);
        _appLifetime.StopApplication();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Where `MyCustomProgress` looks like this

```
public class MyCustomProgress
{
    public int Current {get; set;}
    public int Total {get; set;}
}
```

and `MyService` looks something like so (`Job1`, `Job2`, `Job3` implement `IJob`)

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private void List<IJob> _jobsToRun;

    public MyService()
    {
        _jobsToRun.Add(new Job1());
        _jobsToRun.Add(new Job2());
        _jobsToRun.Add(new Job3());
    }

    public void RunJobs(IProgress<MyCustomProgress> progress)
    {           
        _jobsToRun.ForEach(job => 
        {
            job.Execute();

            progress.Report(new MyCustomProgress { Current = _jobsToRun.IndexOf(job) + 1, Total = _jobsToRun.Count() });
        });
    }

}
```

And `IJob` is

```
public interface IJob
{
    void Execute();
}
```

This setup works well and I'm able to display the progress bar from my `HostedService` by creating a `ShellProgressBar` instance and using the one `IProgress` instance I have to update it.

However, I have another implementation of `IMyService` that I also need to run that looks something like this

```
public class MyService2 : IMyService
{
    private void List<IJob> _sequentialJobsToRun;
    private void List<IJob> _parallelJobsToRun;

    public MyService()
    {
        _sequentialJobsToRun.Add(new Job1());
        _sequentialJobsToRun.Add(new Job2());
        _sequentialJobsToRun.Add(new Job3());


        _parallelJobsToRun.Add(new Job4());
        _parallelJobsToRun.Add(new Job5());
        _parallelJobsToRun.Add(new Job6());
    }

    public void RunJobs(IProgress<MyCustomProgress> progress)
    {       
        _sequentialJobsToRun.ForEach(job => 
        {
            job.Execute();

            progress.Report(new MyCustomProgress { Current = _jobsToRun.IndexOf(job) + 1, Total = _jobsToRun.Count() });
        });

        Parallel.ForEach(_parallelJobsToRun, job => 
        {
            job.Execute();

            // Report progress here
        });
    }

}
```

This is the one I'm struggling with. when `_parallelJobsToRun` is executed, I need to be able to create a new child `ShellProgressBar` (`ShellProgressBar.Spawn`) and display them as child progress bars of let's say 'Parallel Jobs'.

This is where I'm looking for some help as to how I can achieve this.

Note: I don't want to take a dependency on `ShellProgressBar` in my class library containing `MyService`

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What’s the point of using Parallel.ForEach on a list of tasks? Tasks already run in the background and thus in parallel. So all you are doing is wasting costly threads in Parallel just to kickoff another thread with Task.Run. You shouldn’t mix Parallel.ForEach and tasks as both use valuable thread resources. If you want code to run in parallel and be highly scalable use Parallel, if you want to run code asynchronously (which also runs in parallel) use Task.

Comment: I can see why the confusion. In this example I've called it Task but it's not the C# task. I've updated the sample code to articulate that better.

Comment: Do these *`"IJob`"* derived jobs even have the ability to report their progress?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I've re-written my question with detailed sample code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try using Hangire. It's an easy way to perform background processing in .NET and .NET Core applications. No Windows Service or separate process required. It's open source too.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your description, but let's see if I understand what you are up to.  So if you wrap all of this in a class, then taskList1 and taskList2 could be class variables.  (By the way taskList1/2 should be named better: say parallelTaskList and whatever . . . anyway.)  Then you could write a new method on the class CheckTaskStatus() and just iterate over the two class variables.  Does that help or have I completely missed your question?

Comment: Iterating over them would require the console app to know about the possible class variables but I am not able to do that. The class library is agnostic of who's calling it and the console app is agnostic of how many steps there are in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify it like this?

```
public Task<ICollection<IProgress<int>>> StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var progressList = _myServiceFromLibrary.RunTasks();

    return Task.FromResult(progressList);
}

public ICollection<IProgress<int>> RunTasks()
{
    var taskList1 = new List<ITask> { Task1, Task2 };
    var plist1 = taskList1.Select(t => t.Progress).ToList();
    var taskList2 = new List<ITask> { Task3, Task4, Task5 }:
    var plist2 = taskList2.Select(t => t.Progress).ToList();

    taskList1.foreach( task => task.Run() );

    Parallel.Foreach(taskList2, task => { task.Run() });

    return plist1.Concat(plist2).ToList();
}
```

`Task.Progress` there is probably a progress getter. realistically IProgress should probably be injected via Tasks constructors. But the point is your public interface doesn't accept list of tasks, thus it should just return collection of progress reports.

How to inject progress reporters into your tasks is a different story that depends on tasks implementations and it may or may not be supported. out of the box.

However what you probably should do is to supply progress callback or progress factory so that progress reporters of your choice are created:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action<Task,int> onprogress)
{
    _myServiceFromLibrary.RunTasks(onprogress);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public class SimpleProgress : IProgress<int>
{
    private readonly Task task;
    private readonly Action<Task,int> action;
    public SimpleProgress(Task task, Action<Task,int> action)
    {
        this.task = task;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void Report(int progress)
    {
        action(task, progress);
    }
}

public ICollection<IProgress<int>> RunTasks(Action<Task,int> onprogress)
{
    var taskList1 = new List<ITask> { Task1, Task2 };
    taskList1.foreach(t => t.Progress = new SimpleProgress(t, onprogress));
    var taskList2 = new List<ITask> { Task3, Task4, Task5 }:
    taskList2.foreach(t => t.Progress = new SimpleProgress(t, onprogress));

    taskList1.foreach( task => task.Run() );

    Parallel.Foreach(taskList2, task => { task.Run() });
}
```

you may see here, that it really is mostly question about how your tasks are going to call `IProgress<T>.Report(T value)` method.

Comment: Hi, I seem to have given the false impression in my question that my tasks were the  C# `Task` type but I meant that in the literal sense. I've updated my question now. How would you modify this answer with this in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would just use an event in your task prototype.

It's not really clear exactly what you want because the code you posted doesn't match the names you then reference in your question text... It would be helpful to have all the code (the RunTasks function for example, your IProgress prototype, etc).

Nevertheless, an event exists specifically to signal calling code. Let's go back to the basics. Let's say you have library called MyLib, with a method DoThings().

Create a new class that inherits from EventArgs, and that will carry your task's progress reports...

```
public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int _taskId;
    private int _percent;
    private string _message;


    public int TaskId => _taskId;
    public int Percent => _percent;
    public string Message => _message;

    public ProgressEventArgs(int taskId, int percent, string message)
    {
        _taskId = taskId;
        _percent = percent;
        _message = message;
    }
}
```

Then on your library's class definition, add an event like so:

```
public event EventHandler<ProgressEventArgs> Progress;
```

And in your console application, create a handler for progress events:

```
void ProgressHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
    // Do whatever you want with your progress report here, all your
    // info is in the e variable
}
```

And subscribe to your class library's event:

```
var lib = new MyLib();
lib.Progress += ProgressHandler;
lib.DoThings();
```

When you are done, unsubscribe from the event:

```
lib.Progress -= ProgressHandler;
```

In your class library, now you can send back progress reports by raising the event in your code. First create a stub method to invoke the event:

```
protected virtual void OnProgress(ProgressEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = Progress;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

And then add this to your task's code where you want it:

```
OnProgress(new ProgressEventArgs(2452343, 10, "Reindexing google..."));
```

The only thing to be careful about is to report progress sparingly, because each time your event fires it interrupts your console application, and you can really bog it down hard if you send 10 million events all at once. Be logical about it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I've re-written my question with detailed sample code.

Comment: Hi, even with your updated answer, I think this approach still fits the bill

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between this and using `IProgress` to solve my core problem, which is multiple progress events being sent back to the caller, per `Job()` from `_parallelJobsToRun` so that I can display a progress bar for each of them simultaneously.

I think your method would work as well but only for one progress report at a time but not when you want to get multiple progress updates, right? Or have I misunderstood your implementation?

Comment: I think you missed the property I put in the ProgressEventArgs, TaskId. You need to identify your jobs when reporting, but any number of them can report. This does the same thing you are trying to do, but the standard, Microsoft approved pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way; If you own the code `IProgress<T>` and `Progress`

```
IProgress<T>
{
   IProgress<T> CreateNew();    
   Report(T progress);
}

Progress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
  Progress(ShellProgressClass)
  {
    // initialize progressBar or span new
  }   
  ....
   IProgress<T> CreateNew()
   {
     return new Progress();
   }
}
```

you can later improvise to have one big progressBar (collection of Sequential or Parallel) and what not

Answer (score 0):

Your MyService could have a dependency similar to:

```
public interface IJobContainer
{
    void Add(IJob job);

    void RunJobs(IProgress<MyProgress> progress, Action<IJob>? callback = null); // Using an action for extra work you may want to do
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about reporting progress in MyService (which doesn't feel like it should be MyService's job anyway. The implementation could look something like this for the parallel job container:

```
public class MyParallelJobContainer
{
    private readonly IList<IJob> parallelJobs = new List<IJob>();

    public MyParallelJobContainer()
    {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public void Add(IJob job) { ... }

    void RunJobs(IProgress<MyProgress> progress, Action<IJob>? callback = null)
    {
        using (var progressBar = new ProgressBar(options...))
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(parallelJobs, job =>
            {
                callback?.Invoke(job);
                job.Execute();
                progressBar.Tick();
            })
        }
    }
}
```

MyService would then look like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IJobContainer sequentialJobs;
    private readonly IJobContainer parallelJobs;

    public MyService(
        IJobContainer sequentialJobs,
        IJobContainer parallelJobs)
    {
        this.sequentialJobs = sequentialJobs;
        this.parallelJobs = parallelJobs;

        this.sequentialJobs.Add(new DoSequentialJob1());
        this.sequentialJobs.Add(new DoSequentialJob2());
        this.sequentialJobs.Add(new DoSequentialJob3));

        this.parallelJobs.Add(new DoParallelJobA());
        this.parallelJobs.Add(new DoParallelJobB());
        this.parallelJobs.Add(new DoParallelJobC());
    }

    public void RunJobs(IProgress<MyCustomProgress> progress)
    {
        sequentialJobs.RunJobs(progress, job => 
        {
             // do something with the job if necessary
        });

        parallelJobs.RunJobs(progress, job => 
        {
             // do something with the job if necessary
        });
    }
```

The advantage of this way is that MyService only has one job and doesn't have to worry about what you do once the job is completed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I like the direction with this, however I think this has the same limitation as my original question. When the parallel jobs are executed, it's going to `Tick()` when each job is finished. Which means the `IProgress` won't be able to report the progress of each individual `IJob`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your issue the question is how do you display progress across *both* completion of the synchronous jobs and parallelized jobs.

In theory the parallel jobs could start and finish at the same time, so you could treat the parallel jobs as a single job. Instead of using the count of sequential jobs as your total, increase that number by one. This might be satisfactory for a small number of parallel jobs.

If you want to add progress between the parallel jobs, you will need to handle multi-threading in your code because the parallel jobs will be running *concurrently*.

```
object pJobLock = new object();
int numProcessed = 0;
foreach(var parallelJob in parallelJobs)
{
    parallelJob.DoWork();
    lock (pJobLock)
    {
        numProcessed++;
        progress.Report(new MyCustomProgress { Current = numProcessed, Total = parallelJobs.Count() });
    }
}
```